# how to call in a EJB 3 a CDI Injection from a different jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi, ejb-3.1

How is it possible to call in a EJB3 container(jar1) a CDI injection from a different jar(jar2)?

When I trying to deploy the application on the Glassfish 4.1 I get this error message:

```
Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type **** with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ****
  at ....
```

When I put in the EJB (jar1) a CDI pojo (jar1)and try to call it in the EJB it will work. The same is when I try to call the CDI pojo from (jar2) in the not EJB Container(jar3)

Comment: do you have beans.xml in all your jars?

Comment: yes i have in all jars an beans.xml

Comment: based on the fact you are using glassfish 4.1.1, you may be using cdi 1.2, in that case, if you have beans.xml, specifying version 1.2, make sure that bean is annotated if the cdi bean scanning is specified as annotated in the beans.xml

Comment: in j2ee 7 you dont have to define a empty bean.xml. I try it with bean.xml and without. Change Nothing

Comment: i create a example what i have try to install on wildfly! it works but on glassfish 4.1 it will NOT work

Comment: wildfly has a different classpath management system than glassfish.  the best way to enable this is to encapsulate the jars into the same EAR file, that way they are part of the same deployment, which then should produce the effect you desire.